# Explain why multiplying "negative" unsigned numbers produces the correct result

Tags: c

I simply cannot comprehend how multiplying 4294967294 with 4294967292 can produce 8.

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int a = -2;
unsigned int b = -4;

int main()
{
    printf( "a     = %u\n"
            "b     = %u\n"
            "a * b = %u\n", 
            a, b, a*b
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Please provide step-by-step explanation of what is happening to the bits and why. If possible, provide evidence that this is legal under the C99 or C11 Standard. Comment if this would pass "code review".

Comment: Because 2s complement.

Comment: Consider the easy 8-bit case: `-2` and `-4` are `FEh` and `FCh` respectively. Their product is `FA08h` which modulo `100h` is the the expected `8`. Being unsigned, the behaviour is completely defined by the C standard.

Comment: And for your 32-bit case the product is `FFFFFFFA00000008h`, which modulo 2³² is `8`.

Comment: This is all written in the standard, for example https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2 explains `unsigned int a = -2;` and such, and https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9 explains the multiplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let *w* be the number of bits in `unsigned int`. Then the maximum number an `unsigned int` can represent is 2<sup>*w*</sup>−1, and one more than that is 2<sup>*w*</sup>.

C 2018 6.2.5 9 says:

> … A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

and 6.3.1.3 1 and 2 say, about conversion to an unsigned integer type:

> … if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise… the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

Thus, any conversion to or computation with `unsigned int` wraps modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>.

Consider `unsigned int a = -2;`. −2 cannot be represented in `unsigned int`, so it is adjusted by adding 2<sup>*w*</sup>. That produces 2<sup>*w*</sup>−2, which is representable. (If *w* is 32, 2<sup>*w*</sup>−2 is 4,294,967,294.)

Similarly, in `unsigned int b = -4;`, 2<sup>*w*</sup> is added to −4, and `b` is initialized to 2<sup>*w*</sup>−4 (4,294,967,292 if *w* is 32).

Now consider `a*b`. `a` is 2<sup>*w*</sup>−2 and `b` is 2<sup>*w*</sup>−4, so the mathematical result would be (2<sup>*w*</sup>−2) • (2<sup>*w*</sup>−4) = 2<sup>*w*</sup>•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 2<sup>*w*</sup>•−4 + −2•2<sup>*w*</sup> + −4•−2 = 2<sup>2*w*</sup> − 6•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 8.

This is too large to represent in `unsigned int`, so it is reduced modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>. Observe that 2<sup>2*w*</sup> − 6•2<sup>*w*</sup> is a multiple of 2<sup>*w*</sup>, so reducing 2<sup>2*w*</sup> − 6•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 8 modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup> yields 8.

To see what is happening with the bits, consider the mathematical result, 2<sup>2*w*</sup> − 6•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 8. This is (2<sup>*w*</sup> − 6)•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 8. In binary, (2<sup>*w*</sup> − 6)•2<sup>*w*</sup> is the binary numeral for 2<sup>*w*</sup> − 6 shifted left 2<sup>*w*</sup> bits. So it ends with *w* 0 bits. To that, we add eight. So if we take the binary numeral for 2<sup>2*w*</sup> − 6•2<sup>*w*</sup> + 8 and discard the high bits, keeping only the low *w* bits, we are left with a binary numeral for 8.

For example, with *w* = 32, 2<sup>64</sup> − 6•2<sup>32</sup> + 8 is 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000<sub>2</sub>. The low 32 bits are 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000<sub>2</sub>, which represents 8.

Comment: Don't answer questions where the asker has very obviously made no effort.

Comment: @IanKemp: Stack Overflow is for answering questions. Gatekeeping knowledge is undesirable. For debugging questions, it is reasonable to expect somebody to make an effort to debug their program and to develop the skills for that. For more abstract knowledge questions, it is reasonable that somebody may be stuck and not know how to proceed.

Comment: It's not about gatekeeping. It's about preventing Stack Overflow from turning into an IT support helpdesk. If you want to run an IT support helpdesk, you're welcome to do so elsewhere.

Comment: @IanKemp: I am welcome to answer questions on Stack Overflow, and I will continue to do so.